# Wine program errors

Tags: wine

when I run any wine program, program errors are appearing:

[image: errors]

Sometimes winemenubuilder.exe is appearing too. winecfg doesn't work as well (Wine program crash: Internal errors - invalid parameters received) 
What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete the .wine folder in your home folder (Ctrl+H to see it)
Do you have the latest Wine version ?
[This link shows you how to do it](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)
So, if you have a 64 bits architecture, do

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

Comment: yes I have the latest version 1.9.22 and I use Ubuntu 16.04 amd64

Comment: If I delete .wine folder, what will happen?

Comment: Your users .wine data will be deleted (not the program itself), and wine will create a new folder with the default settings the next time you launch it.

Comment: You will also lose everything in you Program File folder (which is in .wine/drive_c) so all your wine applications. I suggest to back up them or simply to reinstall them

Comment: Thanks you really, I followed your advise and now the problem solved)

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly for me having the same problem :)